# Building many hash tables

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got a tree of 125,000 nodes (at most 2 children). I'm trying to determine the number of children (direct and indirect) of each node. Because the tree is a DAG *but* the number of links to each child is unbounded, many nodes will have virtually all of the other nodes as children. The total complexity of the tree, just for reference, is way over 10^30 if expressed without memoization. This means that, even storing a simple pointer to each child (and memoizing the output) produces a 15.625GB lump of data, even ignoring hash table, memory allocator, and other overhead.

While this is the desired output, it's taking a little too long and a little too much memory to achieve. I've only got a single workstation, of fair but not top-of-the-line power (i7 930, 6GB RAM).

Is there any way that I can memoize or otherwise cache the tables so that the data is still accessible in a reasonable period of time (I will be doing potentially hundreds of thousands of accesses on the data)? I've considered lazily evaluating the queries, but I'm concerned about how long it would take to access them.

In addition, I'm not specifically interested in which nodes are children, but I *do* need to know the *number* of them- which basically amounts to the same thing I believe, as I can't count the same child twice.

Edit: The tree is immutable. All I will do is read the number of children.

Comment: How exactly do you want to use this information i.e. how do you want to query it?  Also, how will you consume this information?  I have several possible solutions but I need a bit more context on the problem in order to offer one that will be at all relevant or useful.

Edit:  Will nodes be changing their links to other nodes at any point also?  If so, how frequently (or is that information even knowable at all)?

Comment: Couldn't this be put into some kind of database or something? It doesn't seem like you'd need complex queries, so a NoSQL database would likely work just fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas: But would that actually be faster than writing it myself?

Comment: @DeadMG: Consider that databases are *really good* at storing and fetching bulk quantities of data that are associated with other pieces of data. Since that's pretty much what they do. Various database engines have various performance characteristics and so forth, and each engine has ways of making itself faster for different kinds of queries. At the very least, it's worth investigating the options for your particular use case. It couldn't take more than a few hours to integrate something simple like SQLite (assuming some basic familiarity with SQL databases) and find out if its fast enough.

Comment: Related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-bounds-can-be-put-on-counting-reachable-nodes-in-a-dag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to traverse a direct acyclic graph without going over a node twice (for example to count each node once), you can add a `mutable` boolean to each node indicating whether you have traversed the node before.  You can look at all descendants of a nodes by marking the node, looking at the node, and recursively traversing at the unmarked children of the node.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing (effectively). However, I got lucky in that it turns out only a minority of the nodes actually needed this operation performed- I would have been absolutely sunk in run-time if this were not the case.

Comment: @DeadMG Hmm.  It was slow at run-time?  I think this method goes over each node once, which is about fast good as you can do to calculate the number of nodes.  Could you cache the counts reachable nodes within the nodes themselves?

Comment: Not if I want to count each individual node only once. However, don't forget that the tree is very complex, and even memoizing can only reduce that complexity so far, and in addition, I am performing many, *many* queries into it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already found an answer, but just for kicks [the transitive closure of a DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#Graph_theory) might be useful for others thinking about this kind of problem.

[Timothy Chan](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tmchan/) published [a paper in 2005 with a footnote about efficiently computing the transitive closure of a DAG](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tmchan/apsp.ps).  Quoting from the paper:

> ...for the simpler problem of computing the transitive closure of an
>   unweighted directed graph, Yuster and Zwick in a recent paper asked
>   for an O(mn)-time algorithm, but an O(mn/log n + n<sup>2</sup>) time
>   bound is actually easy to get on the word RAM.<sup>2</sup>
>
> ...
>
> <sup>2</sup> Proof: Assume that the graph is acyclic, since we can precompute the
>   strongly connected components in linear time and contract each
>   component.  We want to find the set *S<sub>u</sub>* over all vertices
>   reachable from each vertex *u*.  For each vertex *u* in reverse
>   topological order, we can compute *S<sub>u</sub>* by taking the union of
>   *S<sub>v</sub>* over all vertices *v* incident from *u*.  Each of these O(m)
>   set-union operations can be carried out in O(n/log n) time by
>   representing a set as an (n/log n)-word vector and by using the
>   bitwise-or operation.

Clearly there's still a bit to figure out there -- you need to precompute the "strongly connected components" and have to be able to visit nodes in reverse topological order -- but the process he describes of efficiently taking a repeated union sounds like a reasonable way to count the number of children for a given node in a DAG.

- Timothy M. Chan, **[All-Pairs Shortest Paths with Real Weights in O(n<sup>3</sup>/log n) Time](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tmchan/apsp.ps)**.  *Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 2005, Volume 3608, Algorithms and Data Structures, Pages 318-324.*

Comment: Interesting link!.  However, the posted question uses a binary tree, so the maximum degree of the graph O(1), so the trivial O(mn) algorithm is O(n^2), so the more complicated algorithm doesn't buy you anything.  Still, this might come in handy if the number of child nodes were unbounded and there were many more edges than nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I would cache the number of descendants of a node in the node itself.  Since the nodes are immutable, you can calculate and cache the descendant count and not worry about the cached values becoming stale.

The number of descendants of a given node is 1 plus the sum of the number of descendants of for each of its children (direct children, not indirect descendants).  Since each child has cached the count of its descendants, this is a very fast calculation.

Comment: Nope, because I need to know *which* descendants they have, else I will start counting children twice when they have shared children. With that in mind, even after caching, this is still too much.

Comment: I think we have a difference in nomenclature.  I would say that in a tree, there are no such thing as shared nodes.  Nodes are immutable, so you can secretly use the same memory for two nodes that have the same structure, but logically those nodes are distinct.

Would it be correct for me to say that you need a count of the number of reachable nodes in directed acrylic graph?

Comment: In my tree, those nodes are most definitely not distinct and cannot be counted twice. For one, calling them distinct would make *any* operation on the tree impossible due to it's insane size, and for two, they are logically identical and must, for example, share many properties.

Comment: @DeadMG If you want to traverse all the reachable nodes once and only once in a DAQ, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to break some algorithm? :naughty: The simplest way is to use n/nlogn( work in general ) n ( reference in general ) cases, in which you would store key references to that table, and look up whenever you need particular mapped hash stack. So for instance, n root node has n1 and n2 child nodes, n1 child node is not processed, but referenced and kept somewhere on your disk, but n1 root node( which is basically the same as n1 child node, but without the privelege to be counted ) will be further processed and have n11 and n12 child nodes, then n11 root node will be mapped as a reference to that tree and so on and on. So for instance you would have only 125,000 reference keys with the pointers to other reference keys and if needed something whatever you want, which will your PC truly process, and the rest is only kept to be processed and frittered in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done via a mapreduce approach, since part of the problem is large datasets. It's a very different way to do it, as it's in the realm of text files and clusters rather than C++, but it will at least scale with machine count without impacting time to completion too much.

The method would be to start with key:value pairs denoting each directed edge, and build up the sets of nodes descending from each until each is marked done. When collecting from two child nodes, use the intersection of the sets of children, and maintain the set of incomplete nodes separately. This should take something like 2 maps & collects per level of depth, but obviously with reducing workload as you ascend the graph.

It is obviously more work computationally, but it can leverage the existing hadoop etc systems for ease of scaling.

I suppose there are two levels to this answer: a) consider a multi-pass approach, and b) consider hadoop et al to distribute the work.